# Why does Visual Studio 2017 RC3 try and restore packages for a project no longer in the solution?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore, visual-studio-2017

I have a project called `AcmeSoft.Api` in my working tree, but several builds ago I removed it from the solution. Yet after several VS restarts, and even a repair, every time VS does a package restore, I get the bellow error message:

> Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The operation failed as
>   details for project AcmeSoft.Api could not be loaded.

Comment: structure of .csproj was changed. I forced to create project again.

Comment: maybe try to clean up nuget cache?

Comment: Did this issue occurred in the previous version of Visual Studio 2017 RC3? I have not encountered this issue in the previous version. If this issue only occurred in the Visual Studio 2017 RC3, Could you please submit a ticket and add the link in your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem? Thanks. If this issue still occurred on other version visual studio, please share the detail steps for this issue, so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: I never noticed in previous versions, but then I never had the same circumstances. I will try and duplicate the issue, which seems to have come right, before submitting a ticket. Thanks.

Comment: Have you duplicated the issue? if yes, please share the link of the ticket to us. Thanks.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT, no, I've spent the whole day repairing VS 2015, and still have to repair VS 2017 tomorrow before I can even think about duplicating the issue.

Comment: How do you remove it from the solution?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT, by right-clicking it in solution explorer and choosing `Remove`, then saving everything, closing and reopeding VS to see if I get any `Save` prompts, and to make the the project was removed. I'm still even experiencing this after upgrading to VS 2017 RC 4  on Wednesday, and I'm afraid it's starting to look more like a downgrade

Comment: @ProfK any update on this issue?

Comment: @johnny5 Not yet. Work on that project will resume later today and I will update.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking forward to your updates